# Pure base class needs to be exported from DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, interface, export, abstract-class

I have two DLLs: `a.dll` and `b.dll` and in each one I have one class `AClass` and `BClass`.
I would like to have both `AClass` and `BClass` inherit and implement the same interface `AbsBase` which is a pure abstract class.
In each class I set up the `#defines` for `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspect(dllexport)`. When I'm trying to compile I get this:

> warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'AClass' used as base for dll-interface class 'AbsBase'

which basically wants me to declare `AbsBase` as `__declspec(dllexport)`
But if the compiler would have it his way, I would have to declare `AbsBase` to be exported from both `a.dll` and `b.dll`.

Why does the interface of a class needs to be exported?
Is there any way around it?
Should I really export `AbsBase` from both DLLs? isn't there something inherently wrong with this? (I would need to define a new XXX_EXPORT macro..)

Comment: show us your interface and class declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like its a compiler warning and not an error, so it should still work. The compiler is just letting you know that you are doing something that makes it easy for you to screw up. It should be perfectly acceptable to do this as long as both DLLs and the core program agree on the definition of the base class.

You should be able to use a pragma to supress the warning:

http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-84785.html

Comment: The response from "ralph" in that thread is illuminating. @OP: You won't experience that problem ralph mentions provided that your base class remains pure abstract *forever*.

Comment: Making the base class completely pure virtual solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is something to fret about.  The compiler has detected that code in the base class may run.  It won't be pure a virtual method, it knows how to filter those.  Maybe a constructor or a destructor?  The failure mode is that the memory layout of the class object might not be the same in the client code vs the DLL.  The runtime mayhem this causes is *very* hard to diagnose.

You'll be okay if as long as you can guarantee that both the client and the DLL are compiled with the exact same compile and link settings, using the exact same versions of the CRT and those tools.  You can make the base class guaranteed abstract by using the non-standard __interface keyword instead of class.

Comment: I've run into this warning many times and I've always resolved it by simply exporting the base class definition. Am I missing something? I'll bet there aren't a lot of situations where you'd be okay exporting class `Derived` but *not* okay exporting class `Base`, especially since `__declspec` classes tend to represent user-facing or client-facing large-grained entities with well-defined hiearchies etc., or anyway, stuff that's intended to be *used* externally.

Answer (score 0):

I have a tip:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
    virtual ~Base();
};

class A: public Base {
  public:
    virtual void f();
    virtual void g();
};

class B: public Base {
  public:
    virtual void g(); // REVERSE ORDER
    virtual void f();
};
```

The order of f and g in virtual method table is specified in the base class and this information is very needed.

Comment: Yes, it is.  That's why it is in the header file.